# Update numbers in table with variable and update variable

Tags: php, mysql

As you can see from the table below the user with the id of 1 has 10 points altogether
What I'm trying to do is have one number submitted from a form `$edit_points` to loop through and subtract from user 1
This number could be anything eg:

$edit_points = 6
would subtract 4 from the first record
then move to the next and only subtract the remainder 2
then break out of loop

```
UserID  | TotalPoints      
-------------------
 1      | 4        
 1      | 4      
 1      | 2      
 4      | 3        
 3      | 3       
 5      | 4
```

This is what I've got so far

```
$pointLeft = $edit_points;//sent from form    
while($point = mysqli_fetch_array($output)){

if($pointLeft > $point["TotalPoints"]){//if pointsLeft more than this record
$remainder =  $pointLeft-$point["TotalPoints"];//get remainder
$query2 = "UPDATE pointstable SET TotalPoints=0 WHERE UserID=".$UserID;
$output2 =  $mysqli->query($query2);

}elseif($pointLeft < $point["TotalPoints"]){

$remainder =  $point["TotalPoints"] - $pointLeft;   
$query2 = "UPDATE pointstable SET TotalPoints=".$remainder." WHERE UserID=".$UserID;
$output2 =  $mysqli->query($query2);

}

$pointLeft = $remainder;

}
```

It works to a point and seems to populate all the records with the same last value that remainder holds 
I've tried break and putting an if ($pointLeft<=0) above the first if
but none works.
any help? or a better way of doing it preferably using php

Comment: You'd need some sort of unique ID to be able to change only 1 row... Right now you're only using the UserID in your `WHERE`-clause. That is not unique, so multiple rows are updated!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marty
Revised code below
There's a unique id PointID that I now use

```
$poinstLeft = $edit_points; //sent from form

while($point = mysqli_fetch_array($output)){
    //if pointsLeft more than this record
    if($poinstLeft >= $point["TotalPoints"]){
        //get remainder
        echo $poinstLeft." ";
        $remainder =  $poinstLeft-$point["TotalPoints"];
        $query2 = "UPDATE pointstable SET TotalPoints=0 WHERE UserID=".$UserID." AND PointID=".$point["PointID"];

        $output2 =  $mysqli->query($query2);
        // Calculate new pointsleft
        $poinstLeft = $remainder;

    } elseif ($poinstLeft < $point["TotalPoints"]){
        $remainder =  $point["TotalPoints"] - $poinstLeft;
        echo $poinstLeft." ";
        $query2 = "UPDATE pointstable SET TotalPoints=".$remainder." WHERE UserID=".$UserID." AND PointID=".$point["PointID"] ;
        $output2 =  $mysqli->query($query2);
        // Here, your remainder is different from the upper half of your if-function!
        // So, you don't have to recalculate pointsleft... It's just:
        $poinstLeft = 0;

        // Break the while loop:
     break 2;
    }


}
```